# Inquiry on some performance tuning

Tags: java, list, logic

I've got a simple question regarding data structures in Java.
if i have a method in Java that returns a data structure say something like this

```
private List<String> getResults() {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("One");
    data.add("Two");
    data.add("three");
    data.add("Four");
    return data;
}
```

and i want to iterate through this list directly as a result from the method like this

```
 void iterate() {
    for (String value : getResults())
        System.out.println(value);
 }
```

Would this mean that for every value printed, the method **getResults()** is always called or is it just cached somewhere in memory and always referenced in this context as opposed to this..

```
 void iterate() {
    List<String> results = getResults();
    for (String value : results)
        System.out.println(value);
 }
```

Just extending Knowledge base.Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResults()` is only called once in order to create an `Iterator<String>` instance, which is later used to retrieve the `String`s.

Comment: so does this mean that the Iterator<String> stores the reference the the original result returned?

Comment: @OluDoug There's a single Iterator created by that loop, and it is created based on the original List returned by `getResults()` at the start of the loop. However, if the List being iterated over is modified inside the loop, a ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown.

Comment: Huhh... didn't see that one coming.. Thanx